# How to add from a TStringList to a VirtualTreeView?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

Here is what I am "trying" to achieve

I have a function to generate passwords which I then add into a TStringList after this I should populate the VirtualTreeView with the items but I am having no luck in getting anywhere fast with doing so. How should it be done the correct way? I am still learning and am not a professional.

My function for generating the passwords:

```
function Generate(AllowUpper,AllowLower,AllowNumbers,AllowSymbols:Boolean; PassLen:Integer):String;
const
  UpperList  = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  LowerList  = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  NumberList = '0123456789';
  SymbolList = '!#$%&/()=?@<>|{[]}\*~+#;:.-_';
var
  MyList  : String;
  Index   : Integer;
  i       : Integer;
begin
  Result:='';
  MyList:='';
   //here if the flag is set the elements are added to the main array (string) to process
   if AllowUpper   then MyList := MyList + UpperList;
   if AllowLower   then MyList := MyList + LowerList;
   if AllowNumbers then MyList := MyList + NumberList;
   if AllowSymbols then MyList := MyList + SymbolList;

   Randomize;
   if Length(MyList)>0 then
   for i := 1 to PassLen do
   begin
    Index := Random(Length(MyList))+1;
    Result := Result+MyList[Index];
  end;
end;
```

Here is how I am calling it

```
procedure TMain.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  StrLst: TStringList;
// Timing vars...
  Freq, StartCount, StopCount: Int64;
  TimingSeconds: real;
begin
  vst1.Clear;
  Panel2.Caption := 'Generating Passwords...';
  Application.ProcessMessages;
// Start Performance Timer...
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(Freq);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(StartCount);

  StrLst := TStringList.Create;
  try
  for i := 1 to PassLenEd.Value do
   StrLst.Add(Generate(ChkGrpCharSelect.Checked[0],ChkGrpCharSelect.Checked[1],
    ChkGrpCharSelect.Checked[2],ChkGrpCharSelect.Checked[3],20));
// Stop Performance Timer...
    QueryPerformanceCounter(StopCount);
    TimingSeconds := (StopCount - StartCount) / Freq;
// Display Timing... How long it took to generate
    Panel2.Caption := 'Generated '+IntToStr(PassLenEd.Value)+' passwords in '+
    FloatToStrF(TimingSeconds,ffnumber,1,3)+' seconds';

// Add to VirtualTreeList - here???
finally
    StrLst.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I expect that I am doing this completely the wrong way, I have been trying for 2 days now, it would be great if someone could put me straight with how I should go about it.

Chris

Comment: Why have you selected the virtual tree list? It's a very complex control? Why not user a list view or something else equally simple?

Comment: I was initially using just a standard TListView and a TAdvListView but when adding large ammounts of data it becomes too much, even with BeginUpdate and EndUpdate. I am testing generating against another program that can generate over a million passwords in just under 12 seconds - I have heard that VirtualTreeView is very good for things like this and am trying my best to learn it.

Comment: @David, you should post your last comment as an answer. Two seconds worth of code and it would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Shamballa Not your question, but if performance is your goal, making a couple of simple changes in your routine I managed to generate 1,000,000 passwords (with no display) in less than a second.  With your exact routine my machine takes about 2.2 seconds to generate the same 1,000,000 passwords.

Comment: @Shamballa, other thing.. It looks like you use panels to show messages... why not use Labels?

Comment: @jachguate - with no display I have tested and I can generate it in around the same also: 2.000 seconds but that is on a quad core with 4 gig ram installed - would it be possible to say which changes you made?

Comment: @jachguate - I am using panels only for the moment as all of this is in just a test form and not even using any Delphi naming conventions, I will change to Labels, I just picked a panel for it at the time in haste.

Comment: @Shamballa, I have the code... but is not what you asked, so I'm afraid if I post this as an answer it won't be accepted and maybe down-voted because it really does not respond to your question.  I also don't know if is permitted to me suggest you a new question, anyway, I already did that. Without code, easy to say: don't re-calc the MyList on every call and avoid all string relocation while adding new chars to each new password ;)

Comment: @Shamballa, btw, on multi-core, you can even reduce the time needed to get the complete list by multi-threading.. this is a good example of a procedure that gains with parallelization or process, of course it maybe does not worth the effort, with times lees than one second it looks very well for something a user will want to do from time to time... not all the time, all times. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you really want VirtualTreeView, you can use something like this ...
I'm not sure if this is absolutely clear solution, I'm familiar with records, not only one single variables.

```
procedure TMain.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
    p: PString;
    Freq, StartCount, StopCount: Int64;
    TimingSeconds: real;

begin
  Panel2.Caption := 'Generating Passwords...';
  Application.ProcessMessages;

  QueryPerformanceFrequency(Freq);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(StartCount);

  vst1.BeginUpdate;
  vst1.Clear;

  for i := 1 to PassLenEd.Value do
    begin
      p := VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeData(VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil));
      p^ := Generate(ChkGrpCharSelect.Checked[0],ChkGrpCharSelect.Checked[1], ChkGrpCharSelect.Checked[2],ChkGrpCharSelect.Checked[3],20);
    end;

  vst1.EndUpdate;

  QueryPerformanceCounter(StopCount);
  TimingSeconds := (StopCount - StartCount) / Freq;
  Panel2.Caption := 'Generated '+IntToStr(PassLenEd.Value)+' passwords in '+
  FloatToStrF(TimingSeconds,ffnumber,1,3)+' seconds';
end;
```

And you need to implement OnGetNodeDataSize and OnGetText events to initialize node data size and to display the text.

```
procedure TMain.vst1GetNodeDataSize(
  Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; var NodeDataSize: Integer);
begin
  NodeDataSize := SizeOf(string);
end;

procedure TMain.vst1GetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType;
  var CellText: string);
begin
  CellText := PString(VirtualStringTree1.GetNodeData(Node))^;
end;
```

Edit 1: I've corrected data types UnicodeString -> String

Answer (score 7):

I'd probably stick with TListView but turn it into a virtual list view. Like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate;
begin
  ListView.OwnerData := True;
  ListView.OnData = ListViewData;
  ListView.Items.Count := StringList.Count;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ListViewData(Sender: TObject; ListItem: TListItem);
begin
  ListItem.Caption := StringList[ListItem.Index];
end;
```

You can put millions of items in there in an instant.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, I will now try what you suggest with a TListView. I would still like to know what I should do with the Data for a VirtualTreeList though, I have read quite a few posts on questions regarding this here and it seems that I would use OnGetText? Sorry to keep on about the VirtualTreeList it's just that I really would like to know how it can be used - just a question but if I were to use it would the TStringList way be used also or would a completely different way be needed?

Comment: With a virtual control you store the data in some separate container and respond to events sent by the control when it wants to retrieve data to display. You'd keep the data in the string list with whichever virtual control you use.

Answer (score 3):

You better store your stringlist somewhere else in your code to use it "virtually", e.g. in the form's private section. When after populating it, just set:

```
vst1.Clear;
vst1.RootNodeCount := StrLst.Count;
```

And on tree's get text event:

```
procedure TForm1.vst1GetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
begin
  CellText := StrLst[Node.Index];
end;
```

Comment: +1, it's easier but maybe little bit slower than my version :)

Comment: It will be even faster, because in my version I don't need to add all childs to the tree. Virtual Treeview will create only visible nodes at first.

Comment: @Linas Thank you - this is where is was having major problems in understanding the OnGetText, I was trying to load from a TStringList here but it was all being concatenated together in a large string!

Comment: @Linas - well, I've compared the code inside (adding and getting data) and you're right. @Shamballa - be careful with deletion of the items, because you can get out of index ;)

Comment: Essentially identical to the TListView version. Nice!

Comment: Anyway I'm wondering now, wouldn't be even faster to use array instead of TStringList ?

Comment: @daemon_x - Did you remove your code from here? I was going to accept it as the answer because you gave me a working example which is better for me to learn from, without it I would still be struggling. Those few lines of code you gave actually learnt me quite alot.

Comment: @Shamballa - well, here it is, but if you are storing only set of one variable (in your case list of strings) is this answer good approach. VT is mostly used for storing more complex records and using them differs a bit against my answer. And there are many ways to handle data in VT. Maybe you can find some examples on Mike's website.

Comment: @Linas - Where would be the best place to free this StringList?

Comment: @Shamballa Depends on where you create it. In your example I guess You could create StringList in your form's OnCreate event and free it on form's destroy event.

Comment: @Linas - I have been creating it in the Generate procedure but I could also use OnCreate, the only thing is after each generation the memory usage rises unless I can free it somehow. Everywhere I have tried though I keep getting Invalid Pointer Operation because at that time it is still needed.

Comment: @Linas - I think I may have come up with something and that is to create it using OnCreate then free it just before I start to Generate but create it again further down the procedure.

Comment: @Shaballa No need to free it each time. You can clear the stringlist before You generate all the items.

Comment: @Linas - Thank you kindly for your help again.